# How should I maintain my Puma application server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puma

I can successfully run a rails application on my server using Puma as the application server. I start Puma like this:

```
bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/my_app.sock
```

That is a unix command that starts puma in production mode at the specified location. However, if I need to reboot my vps, I'll need to go through all of my apps and run that command over and over to start the Puma server for each app.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I'm a bit of an Ubuntu noob, but would the best way to be this:

Every time I install a new rails application on my vps, I

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.local
```

and append rc.local with the command? So that rc.local looks like this after a while:

```
  #!/bin/sh -e
  #
  # rc.local
  #

  bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/app_1.sock
  bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/app_2.sock
  bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/app_3.sock
  bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/app_4.sock
  bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/run/app_5.sock

  exit 0
```

Comment: For Unicorn I had to write [my own init script](https://gist.github.com/mdesantis/4740439), as for [delayed_job](https://gist.github.com/mdesantis/5143647); you can look at them and take inspiration. For Ubuntu/Debian the init script template is located in `/etc/init.d/skeleton`, daemons are controlled with the `service` command and enabled/disabled at startup with the `update-rc.d` command. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu makes this very difficult. The simplest solution I've seen so far is with OpenBSD. To make sure your apps start on reboot, add this to your `/etc/rc.conf.local`:

```
pkg_scripts="myapp myapp2 myapp3"
```

Each app would need a startup script like this (`/etc/rc.d/myapp`):

```
#!/bin/sh

# OPENBSD PUMA STARTUP SCRIPT

# Remember to `chmod +x` this file

# http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/ports/infrastructure/templates/rc.template?rev=1.5

puma="/usr/local/bin/puma"
pumactl="/usr/local/bin/pumactl"
puma_state="-S /home/myapp/tmp/puma.state"
puma_config="-C /home/myapp/config/puma.rb"

. /etc/rc.d/rc.subr

rc_start() {
  ${rcexec} "${pumactl} ${puma_state} start ${puma_config}"
}

rc_reload() {
  ${rcexec} "${pumactl} ${puma_state} restart ${puma_config}"
}

rc_stop() {
  ${rcexec} "${pumactl} ${puma_state} stop"
}

rc_check() {
  ${rcexec} "${pumactl} ${puma_state} status"
}

rc_cmd $1
```

Then do like:

```
% /etc/rc.d/myapp start
% /etc/rc.d/myapp reload
% /etc/rc.d/myapp stop
% /etc/rc.d/myapp status
```

Comment: In what way does Ubuntu make this very difficult?

Comment: Not to start an OS war, but everything is just so extremely complicated. Take the standard Puma startup script for instance: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/tools/jungle/init.d/puma

Comment: Yeah you're spot on. I think Puma on average is just harder to make work properly. We used it in production for about a year, and have moved to the new Passenger. Pretty much zero config and zero issues thus far.

Comment: We're talking about Ubuntu, not Puma. The complexity of the startup script I linked is due to Ubuntu. And, as for Puma vs. Passenger, I find the exact opposite to be true - Passenger is an overcomplicated mess with fancy bells and whistles. Every time I ask the Puma author why Passenger does this or that, he just shakes his head in disbelief at how pointless it all is.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses upstart to manage services. Puma actually provides upstart scripts that make it incredibly easy to do what you want. Have a look at the scripts in their repo:

https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart

Comment: `cd /home/deployer/apps/cpp/current && bundle exec pumactl start` is easy, those scripts make my eyes glaze over, but nothing else works. Will have to try, sigh.